# Htaccess "Header set" gives me server error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This code gives me "Internal Server Error"

```
Header set x-robots-Tag: "noodp, noarchive"
```

Some simple mod_rewrite codes work, but this doesn't.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the colon (`:`) in there, just the name and value of the header.

Instead of

```
Header set x-robots-Tag: "noodp, noarchive"
```

Try

```
Header set x-robots-Tag "noodp, noarchive"
```

See examples [in the Apache 2.2 manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html) or [the 2.4 version](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html), depending which your server has.